# Zend Framework - how to apply icon in xml file and retriev it

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

When it load the xml file, the icon cause failure inside the label tags. How to fix it?

```
// horizontal top menu 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <nav>

    <page1>
      <label><img src='icon.icon' /> Page 1</label>
      <controller>index</controller>
    </page1>


    <home>
      <label>Home</label>
      <controller>index</controller>
    </home>
  </nav>
</root>

// controller test
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
$container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
$this->view->navigation($container);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do it with CSS instead

```
// horizontal top menu 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <nav>

    <page1>
      <label>Page 1</label>
      <controller>index</controller>
      <class>menu-page1-icon</class>
    </page1>

  </nav>
</root>
```

CSS

```
.menu-page1-icon:before {
    content: url(path/to/icon.icon);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works with CSS method. Thanks

#tested example:
<style>
  .menu-page1-icon:before {
    content: url(icon/icon.icon);
}
</style>
<?php  echo $this->navigation(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be in a cdata section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <nav>

    <page1>
      <label><![CDATA[<img src='icon.icon' /> Page 1]]></label>
      <controller>index</controller>
    </page1>


    <home>
      <label>Home</label>
      <controller>index</controller>
    </home>
  </nav>
</root>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076.aspx

Comment: Didn't worked, i have output in page as: 
<img src='icon.icon' /> Page 1 instead of "actual image Page1:"